# Facebook / webhooks / conversations events

Tags: facebook, webhooks, messenger

I've configured two applications on two different pages. "Application1" and "Application2"

To both these applications, I've added the the same products (Messenger and Webhooks), in order to get "conversations" and "feed" type notifications. The settings are identical.

On the app "Application1", it works, and I get conversations type notifications.
On the app "Application2", I only get messages type notifications and it's impossible to get conversations type notifications.

Visually, on the app "Application2", the Messenger icon is grayed out, but in the app "Application1", the icon is green.

I don't understand what's not working. Is this a bug?

Comment: _“Visually, on the app "Application2", the Messenger icon is grayed out”_ - which icon, where? // Did you grant the same permissions to both apps? What’s their review status?

Comment: thank you for your answer. The icon under "Products", where all products added to the application are listed : "Analytics", "Messenger", "Webhooks", ... There is a green "check" icon on left. For Messenger, it's gray. The both applications are published. There is the same rights...

Comment: Well if it is gray, then that most likely indicates something is still missing, either regarding configuration, or review …